# file path display Instead of image in jtable

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable, mouse

I use the following code for display image in display at mouse clicked event.when i use the following code it will show the path of the image in particular cell.how to display the image in that particular cell?

```
private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { 
URL url = getClass().getResource("image/Pointer.GIF");
 ImageIcon testIcon = new ImageIcon(url);
 jTable1.setValueAt(testIcon, 0, 2);
}
```

Comment: about the umpfth time: JTable handles icons perfectly well, provided the model returns the correct column class. How often do you plan to ask and get the exact same answer?

Comment: the downvote is for asking the same question again and again and again ...

Answer (score 1):

Write your own reusable component and have itself manage the events. You wrap the `ImageIcon` and its path in a class. Register a click handler for that class and listen to the click event, which is when you change the component in the container. Keep a `state` variable also and swap the contents of the container. To display the `path` create a `JLabel` on the fly and add it to container or you can have a `JLabel` constructed at the time of component creation.

Possible your component starts like this

```
public class MyComponent extends JComponent {
     private JLabel label; //This displays the path
     private ImageIcon image; //This displays the image

     //Create a container of your wish

     //Attach a click handler to both the label and the image or the container

     //OnClick swap the JComponent in your container and repaint()!

     //Construct it like this:
     MyComponent(String path) {
        //Initialize JLabel with "text" as the path
        //Load ImageIcon from the path
     }
}
```

This is just a starting point. This approach creates a reusable component so, you can have multiple "such" components in yout JLabel without any problem and keeps the code clean.

Comment: `ClickHandler` .. `onClick`?  What J2SE has those?

Comment: What I meant is to make the component implement the MouseListener and listen for the `click` event. It was just an abstract explanation.

Comment: Could you edit `ClickHandler` (implies a class name) to 'click handler' (indicates user input required..) etc.?  That, along with the latest edits, would be worthy of an up-vote.

Comment: Im sorry actually, I work mainly with GWT and these are the things I use everyday, I just got a little confused when I was writing about an old framework I used.

Comment: No need for apologies IMO, when we have the ability to edit.  Good answer.  +1

Comment: -1 no need for any custom component - JTable default renderers can handle icons just fine (provided the model returns the correct class for that column)